# How do I convert this simple python code into javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, translation

I was looking at python script when I have across this:

```
randomNumber = random.randint(2, number)-1
```

How can I translate this into javascript?

Thanks?

Comment: @p.s.w.g I don't think so because I am trying to translate this specific code.

Comment: @Progo It’s exactly what your Python code does though…

Comment: @poke But I already know how to get a random integer in javascript. I just wanted to know how to translate this python code because I don't program in python.

Comment: @Progo Then it sounds like your real question is, "What does this bit of Python do?" See  http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint

Comment: Googling for “random.randint python” gives exactly that link btw.

Comment: Just so that you know. Python's randint method isn't truely random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the examples given in the [`Math.random` docs page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Example%3a_Using_Math.random),

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

console.log(getRandomInt(2, number) - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + number))
```